# Using Nest Elasticsearch with Azure in a web application

Tags: azure, elasticsearch, web-hosting, nest

I have created a web application using visual studio 2013 and used elasticsearch for search services. Now I want to host the website and for this part, I want to use Microsoft Azure.
My challenge is about including elsaticsearch service to Azure.
In order to learn the instruction I have had searched alot and found some resources such as:

- using elasticsearch-could-azure plugin through https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-cloud-azure
- The instruction in [How to use NEST/elasticsearch with Azure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30967713/how-to-use-nest-elasticsearch-with-azure)

But the instruction of both resources makes me confused of what to do exactly in order to be able to host the website with a runnable elasticsearch.

Does anyone knows a much clear step-by-step instruction how to enable elasticsearch in Microsoft Azure?

**UPDATE**:
To find out a step-by-step solution I looked for more resources and found the below links:
1. http://thomasardal.com/running-elasticsearch-in-a-cluster-on-azure/

2. http://www.andrewwestgarth.co.uk/blog/post/2014/02/04/Using-the-Elasticsearch-Azure-Plugin-with-Windows-Virtual-Machines.aspx

I am using visual studio 2013 and use C# asp.net; also I use Nest library to be able to use Elasticsearch services. 
I use elastic search 1.5.2
Here is a step-by-step instruction that I followed:
According to the first link:

1.Creating a subscription in Microsoft Azure.  I have published the web app on Azure and it works fine.

2.Create Virtual Network. I also set the point to site to true since you need this connection for the time that you want to connect the web app to VNet.

3.Create Cloud Service

4. Create 3 Virtual machines and use the created cloud service for each of them.

5.Modify config file of elasticsearch (elasticsearch.yml). uncommenting the mentioned lines in the first link I mentioned above and also adding the internal IP of VMs like the following:

```
cluster.name: recsys-cluster
discovery.zen.ping.multicast.enabled: false
discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts: ["10.0.0.4", "10.0.0.5", "10.0.0.6"]
```

6. Adding Endpoints to the VMs exactly the same as what is said in the link.
7. Changing the code of elasticsearch Uri in my app:

   var node = new Uri("http://recsys-vs-01.cloudapp.net");

I still have problem to run my web app on Azure on the pages that use elasticsearch services.
Can Anyone help me where I am doing something wrong or missing something??

According to the second link above, I also have tried using elasticsearch-cloud-azure plugin but it does not help as well.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Would a hosted Elasticsearch solution such as Found (https://www.elastic.co/found) work for you?

Comment: I have also checked out Found. It should be workable as well, but since I am using Microsoft dependent technologies, I have decided to use Azure for web hosting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally got where I was doing wrong!
It might be a silly missing point for those who are expert in cloud services and virtual machines but for me as a beginner took about a week to figure it out what is missing!
Actually, I didn't install Elasticsearch on Virtual machines as the instruction says. I would think that only setting the internal IPs in configuration file is enough for installation but it is not!

What I should have done was to go to the page of each of the VMs and push the **Connect button** which is located at the bottom of the page; then after giving the same username and password made while creating VMs, you can get access to windows server and install elasticsearch exactly the same as how you do it in your local system.
So just follow this helpful link: http://thomasardal.com/running-elasticsearch-in-a-cluster-on-azure/
hope it is usefull for some beginners like me! :-)